# Trouble matching XML elements that has namespace attribute

Tags: xslt

How would the conditional statement look like if I'm to insert a section of text into the xml below using xslt?

```
<items xmlns="http://mynamespace.com/definition">
    <item>
        <number id="1"/>
    </item>
    <item>
        <number id="2"/>
    </item>
    <!-- insert the below text -->
    <reference>
        <refNo id="a"/>
        <refNo id="b"/>
    </reference>
    <!-- end insert -->
</items>
```

This is how my xsl looks like at the moment (the condition is wrong...):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns="http://mynamespace.com/definition"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:param name="addRef">
        <reference>
            <refNo id="a"/>
            <refNo id="b"/>
        </reference>
    </xsl:param>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- here is where the condition got stuck... -->
    <xsl:template match="/items[namespace-url()=*]/item[position()=last()]">
        <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$addRef"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I wanted to add the reference section after the bottom-most , but I got stuck with how to get around matching an element that has a (explicit) namespace.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
match="//*[local-name()='items']/*[local-name()='item'][position()=last()]"
```

Answer (score 5):

A better, and more elegant, way to solve this would be to use a prefix for your namespace. I prefer working with a null default namespace and using prefixes for all defined namespaces.

Matching on  `fn:local-name()` would match on the local name of the node in all namespaces. All that's needed in your matching condition if using a prefix for your namespace is `my:item[last()]`.

**Input:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items xmlns="http://mynamespace.com/definition">
  <item>
    <number id="1"/>
  </item>
  <item>
    <number id="2"/>
  </item>
</items>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
  xmlns:my="http://mynamespace.com/definition">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:param name="addRef">
    <!-- We set the default namespace to your namespace for this
         certain result tree fragment. -->
    <reference xmlns="http://mynamespace.com/definition">
      <refNo id="a"/>
      <refNo id="b"/>
    </reference>
  </xsl:param>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="my:item[last()]">
    <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$addRef"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items xmlns="http://mynamespace.com/definition">
  <item>
    <number id="1"/>
  </item>
  <item>
    <number id="2"/>
  </item>
  <reference>
    <refNo id="a"/>
    <refNo id="b"/>
  </reference>
</items>
```